# Connecting iPhone to Windows 10 Computer for USB hotspot

Tags: ios, tethering

I have an iPhone 8+ with iOS 12.2 installed. I'm trying to connect it to a Windows 10 computer with a USB cable so I can access the Internet using the iPhone as a hotspot.

I've had success with Android in the past, but I can't seem to get it with my iPhone.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest connecting to your iPhone hotspot over Wi-Fi. The USB connection works like a charm on Macs, but the interaction with non-Apple products can be flaky.

The support document from Apple explains this in detail, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204023.

Keep your iPhone displaying the Personal Hotspot page while you try to connect your Windows device over Wi-Fi.

Once you have that working, if you try USB again, be sure you have iTunes running and that you click "Trust" when prompted by your phone and your PC regarding the connection.

Normally there's no performance advantage from using USB vs. Wi-Fi.

Also, be sure your plan allows you to use your phone as a Hot Spot. I have friends with T-Mobile and AT&T plans for whom this silently fails unless they pay an extra $30/month to their wireless provider.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I don't have iTunes on the client computer. That's probably a big part of the issue.

Comment: fyi: iTunes contains the windows iPhone drivers, so you need to have installed iTunes.