# Issues with routine tasks when connecting Iphone to Windows 10 via USB

Tags: iphone, windows, usb, tethering

So lately I started connecting my iphone 8 to my windows 10 computer on a regular basis. I'm experiencing the following issues:

1. I'm repeatedly asked "Allow the computer to access photos and videos?", every time I connect.
2. When ITunes is open I am required to confirm I trust the device every time (and provide pincode).
3. Trying to tether/hotspot via USB. It doesn't work (found answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359835/connecting-iphone-to-windows-10-computer-for-usb-hotspot), but seems relevant to the context a flaky windows-iphone connection).

Any suggestions?